# Problem deploying my war file with tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, deployment, war

So iwasted nearly a day trying to get tomcat to accept my .war, so maybe you guys can help me.

What I did:

- copied .war file to /webapps directory
- stoppped tomcat using "sudo systemctl stop tomcat8"
- started tomcat using "sudo systemctl start tomcat8"

Afterwards i checked if my app was there and still got the default "It Works!" page of tomcat back. So i checked catalina.out and there were this lines:

```
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.403 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.404 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.54 (Debian)
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.480 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:25.324 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
25-Aug-2020 22:14:37.168 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JS$
25-Aug-2020 22:14:37.785 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [13,303] ms
25-Aug-2020 22:14:37.788 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:39.592 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JS$
25-Aug-2020 22:14:39.602 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [1,815] ms
25-Aug-2020 22:14:39.648 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:39.694 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 15388 ms
```

So I assumed the problem was that the stadard **ROOT** app was deployed after my **demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war** app. So i deleted the **ROOT** folder and restarted the server but my service is still not reachable. Now I just get a 404 error page. catalina.out:

```
25-Aug-2020 22:36:17.865 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
25-Aug-2020 22:36:17.865 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.54 (Debian)
25-Aug-2020 22:36:17.941 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
25-Aug-2020 22:36:18.806 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
25-Aug-2020 22:36:30.742 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JS$
25-Aug-2020 22:36:31.339 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [13,396] ms
25-Aug-2020 22:36:31.349 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2020 22:36:31.380 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 13611 ms
```

So it literally is deploying my war file - but anyhow not completely.
i tried to call the service with **{ip}:80/** and **{ip}:80/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/**

Additional information:

- the tomcat is located on a raspberry pi that is about 100km away from me right now
- the raspberry pi also hosts a pi-hole for the network there
- the catalina.out log had additional lines (with warnings) at every of the two startups. I'm posting the complete log from the first startup at the end

I hope I've given enough information!
Thank you in advance

```
25-Aug-2020 22:13:21.422 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
25-Aug-2020 22:13:22.213 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
25-Aug-2020 22:13:34.872 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Aug-2020 22:13:35.146 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [13,723] ms
25-Aug-2020 22:14:15.314 INFO [Thread-4] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:15.337 INFO [Thread-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:15.460 INFO [Thread-4] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:15.467 INFO [Thread-4] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.166 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.176 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.177 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.177 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.181 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.182 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.183 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.184 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.186 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.186 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.187 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:22.188 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.738 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.54 (Debian)
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.739 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 22 2020 15:22:27 UTC
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.739 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.54.0
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.740 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.740 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.19.66-v7+
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.740 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          arm
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.741 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.741 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat8
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.743 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.744 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.744 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.744 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.746 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.746 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.747 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.747 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp
25-Aug-2020 22:14:23.747 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/arm:/lib:/usr/lib]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.191 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.257 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1953 ms
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.403 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.404 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.54 (Debian)
25-Aug-2020 22:14:24.480 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:25.324 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
25-Aug-2020 22:14:37.168 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Aug-2020 22:14:37.785 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [13,303] ms
25-Aug-2020 22:14:37.788 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:39.592 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Aug-2020 22:14:39.602 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [1,815] ms
25-Aug-2020 22:14:39.648 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2020 22:14:39.694 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 15388 ms
```

Comment: And is there anything (a page) mapped for `{ip}:80/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/`? If you have't told your Spring app to handle `/` with a default page it won't do anything. Also is it really running on port 80 or is there a proxy that forwards port 80 to 8080 of tomcat?

Comment: Yes there is a mapping for ```/```. It's a full working spring boot application. And yes there is a proxy forwarding port 80 to 8080. But it worked with the vanilla page of tomcat.

Comment: Can you please show the mapping for `/` in your spring boot configuration? Have you checked the application log instead of only the catalina logs.